# Writing to CSV using a single string returns 1 character per line

Tags: python, csv

Ive been attempting to write data to a csv file. I have been converting code from java to python and here is the python code:

```
def resultsToCSVStr(results):
    output = "Episode No.,"

    for run in results:
        output += "Run" + str(run) + "steps,"

    for time in range(len(results[0])):

        output += "\n" + str(time) + ","
        for run in range(len(results)):
            output += "" + str(results[run][time]) + ","

    return output


def resultsToCSVFile(results, experimentName):
    resultsTable = resultsToCSVStr(results)
    #print(resultsTable)

    with open("out/" + experimentName + "/" + experimentName + "_stepsToGoal.csv", mode='w') as out:
        writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter="\n")
        writer.writerows(resultsTable)
```

The expected output is in the form:

> EpisodeNo.,Run0steps,Run1steps,Run2steps,Run3steps,Run4steps,Run5steps,Run6steps,Run7steps,Run8steps,Run9steps,

> 0,98,100,100,97,100,100,100,100,100,100,

> 1,14,34,37,40,47,45,29,56,31,31,

> 2,37,30,12,29,29,20,22,31,29,24,

> 3,10,10,16,8,16,10,16,8,10,10,

> 4,16,8,16,8,12,49,8,8,14,14,

However the actual output is

E

p

i

s

o

d

e

N

o

.

,

R

u

n

[

And so on for the entirity of the results. When i print out results table, it returns it correctly deliminated, so the problem lies in the last 3 lines. When i removed the "\n" from the first function it still outputted the same so that isnt even part of the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

### Edit

I changed:

```
writer.writerows(resultsTable)
```

to

```
writer.writerow(resultsTable)
```

And it changed the output, it is still the same problem, but the output doesnt have a gape anymore. I dont think this really changes anything but thought id add.

Comment: Could you share how the `results` structure should like?

Comment: @quantummind I already have above? Unless are you talking about the print results table?

Comment: The CSV writer is responsible for building CSV, not you. You're not supposed to pass a CSV string to `writerows`.

Comment: Ah I see, well is there an alternative as i already have the formatting of the string and simply want to upload it as a csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only had the ability to come back and answer this now, and while my answer is quite specific for the needs of the project, i thought I would show it anyway in case someone was stuck and needed a sample :)

```
def resultsToCSVFile(results1, experimentName, numRuns, numEpisodes, experimentList):
    output = [["" for _ in range(numRuns * len(experimentList) + len(experimentList))] for _ in range(numEpisodes)]

    output[0][0] = "Episode No. "
    for exp in range(len(experimentList)):

        for run in range(numRuns):
            output[0][(run + 1 + (exp * (numRuns + 1)))] = 'Run' + str(exp + 1) + "_" + str(run + 1)

        for run in range(numRuns + 1):
            for episode in range(0, numEpisodes):
                if run == 0 and episode > 0:
                    output[episode][0] = episode
                elif episode == 0:
                    continue
                else:
                    output[episode][run + exp * (numRuns + 1)] = results1[0][
                    ((episode - 1) + numEpisodes * (run - 1) + exp * numRuns * numEpisodes)]

    with open("out/" + experimentName + "/" + experimentName + "_stepsToGoal.csv", mode='w', newline='') as out:
        writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerows(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `csv.writer(out, delimiter=",")` instead od delimiter '\n'. Cause delimiter is symbol between two cells in a row. You also do not need function resultsToCSVStr at all. Just change resultsTable = resultsToCSVStr(results) to resultsTable = results. But firstly, divide results on rows this way:

```
row_len = 3 # Or any row length you want
answer = []
tmp = []
for i, s in enumerate(result[0]):
    tmp.append(s)
    if (i + 1) % row_len == 0:
        answer.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
answer.append(tmp)
result = answer
```

Comment: Unfortunatelty it returns the same output

Comment: No need to be so rude. I see, well i just had concerns as that would return everything in one row no?

Comment: Results is just one giant set of numbers. One row.

Comment: @ConnnK ok, can you give an example of variable result content in the beginning of resultsToCSVFile function? It looks like you use it firstly like array of strings, than like array of arrays.

Actually, to be turned into a csv table, it should have structure:
`[['col1','col2', 'col3'],[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: PS. I did not mean to be rude

Comment: No worries, it must have been a miscommunication. Yes sure, the output of the initial result is [[100, 100, 28, 28, 33, 33, 100, 100, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,.... 4]]

Comment: Ok. Then you firstly need to divide `result[0]` to groups (like `[['col1','col2', 'col3'],[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`), after give result in `csv.writer`

Comment: Okay thanks! How would i go about that if you dont mind?

Comment: @ConnnK by simple work with lists. I gave an example at the end of my answer (cause I can not code in comments)